# Como ler um arquivo .Json pelo Delphi

Tags: delphi-10

Estou com dificuldade em ler um arquivo *.Json* pelo Delphi.
a minha intenção é ler e colara seu conteúdo no banco de dados.
já visualizei alguns links mais nem um atendeu ao que eu queria.

Seque o conteúdo do *.Json*. **Todos os dados aqui são frutos de um gerador de um *fake name generator* sendo todos fictícios.**

```
[
    {
        "nome": "Mariana Isadora Carvalho",
        "idade": 26,
        "cpf": "12956405543",
        "rg": "212055148",
        "data_nasc": "06\/02\/1993",
        "signo": "Aquário",
        "mae": "Ana Aline Esther",
        "pai": "Mateus Eduardo Lucas Carvalho",
        "email": "marianaisadoracarvalho_@agenziamarketing.com.br",
        "senha": "ohaNN4OuyC",
        "cep": "44075169",
        "endereco": "Rua Índia",
        "numero": 694,
        "bairro": "Ponto Central",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7528936096",
        "celular": "75992503534",
        "altura": "1,59",
        "peso": 45,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB-",
        "cor": "verde"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Bruno Márcio Vicente Pires",
        "idade": 62,
        "cpf": "56006359588",
        "rg": "432665389",
        "data_nasc": "18\/07\/1957",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Flávia Sônia Ana",
        "pai": "Daniel Murilo Iago Pires",
        "email": "bbrunomarciovicentepires@pmm.am.gov.br",
        "senha": "sQSR7UXnq8",
        "cep": "44006162",
        "endereco": "Caminho Q - XXI",
        "numero": 304,
        "bairro": "Muchila",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7528175977",
        "celular": "75981475744",
        "altura": "1,92",
        "peso": 109,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A-",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Simone Tânia Figueiredo",
        "idade": 72,
        "cpf": "28366831558",
        "rg": "231064068",
        "data_nasc": "05\/12\/1947",
        "signo": "Sagitário",
        "mae": "Rafaela Larissa Nair",
        "pai": "Cláudio Bernardo Figueiredo",
        "email": "simonetaniafigueiredo__simonetaniafigueiredo@editorazap.com.br",
        "senha": "RjcfZuHBnf",
        "cep": "44089188",
        "endereco": "Caminho 17",
        "numero": 676,
        "bairro": "Brasília",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7526970676",
        "celular": "75989897771",
        "altura": "1,78",
        "peso": 67,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB+",
        "cor": "laranja"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Emanuelly Regina Cecília da Paz",
        "idade": 55,
        "cpf": "54543221567",
        "rg": "285107148",
        "data_nasc": "19\/11\/1964",
        "signo": "Escorpião",
        "mae": "Sara Raimunda Julia",
        "pai": "Murilo Tomás da Paz",
        "email": "emanuellyreginaceciliadapaz..emanuellyreginaceciliadapaz@greenbikeshop.com.br",
        "senha": "rsnRKJsha6",
        "cep": "44035320",
        "endereco": "Caminho 18",
        "numero": 915,
        "bairro": "Campo Limpo",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7525611263",
        "celular": "75983883740",
        "altura": "1,59",
        "peso": 87,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B-",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Maria Amanda Marina Santos",
        "idade": 45,
        "cpf": "99588863597",
        "rg": "483480502",
        "data_nasc": "04\/05\/1974",
        "signo": "Touro",
        "mae": "Márcia Luna Aparecida",
        "pai": "César Renato Santos",
        "email": "mariaamandamarinasantos__mariaamandamarinasantos@mundivox.com.br",
        "senha": "B6E96l0ycd",
        "cep": "44089144",
        "endereco": "Caminho 16",
        "numero": 613,
        "bairro": "Brasília",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7536737134",
        "celular": "75987872328",
        "altura": "1,76",
        "peso": 75,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A-",
        "cor": "preto"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Cláudio Miguel Nicolas da Costa",
        "idade": 61,
        "cpf": "68846188500",
        "rg": "478358246",
        "data_nasc": "09\/04\/1958",
        "signo": "Áries",
        "mae": "Teresinha Tânia",
        "pai": "Lucca Francisco Lorenzo da Costa",
        "email": "claudiomiguelnicolasdacosta_@grupoannaprado.com.br",
        "senha": "b6aCySfcZS",
        "cep": "44024216",
        "endereco": "Rua Juazeiro",
        "numero": 994,
        "bairro": "Jardim Cruzeiro",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7538665016",
        "celular": "75989844202",
        "altura": "1,94",
        "peso": 60,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A-",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Letícia Alessandra Josefa Gonçalves",
        "idade": 76,
        "cpf": "14808239531",
        "rg": "497986814",
        "data_nasc": "11\/10\/1943",
        "signo": "Libra",
        "mae": "Eduarda Fabiana",
        "pai": "Pietro Benedito Gonçalves",
        "email": "lleticiaalessandrajosefagoncalves@bol.com",
        "senha": "MrCPiRjezT",
        "cep": "44065566",
        "endereco": "Rua Patu",
        "numero": 346,
        "bairro": "Conceição",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7525664076",
        "celular": "75987524022",
        "altura": "1,85",
        "peso": 67,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A+",
        "cor": "vermelho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Vicente Edson de Paula",
        "idade": 65,
        "cpf": "21584986506",
        "rg": "180703833",
        "data_nasc": "26\/05\/1954",
        "signo": "Gêmeos",
        "mae": "Marcela Luciana Cecília",
        "pai": "Juan Pietro de Paula",
        "email": "vvicenteedsondepaula@randstad.com.br",
        "senha": "qun83MxRKo",
        "cep": "44088300",
        "endereco": "Rua Almirante Tamandaré",
        "numero": 325,
        "bairro": "Brasília",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7529594328",
        "celular": "75984827098",
        "altura": "1,91",
        "peso": 90,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B+",
        "cor": "amarelo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Davi Gustavo Emanuel Brito",
        "idade": 29,
        "cpf": "57539349514",
        "rg": "420785851",
        "data_nasc": "08\/04\/1990",
        "signo": "Áries",
        "mae": "Stella Eloá",
        "pai": "Gabriel Renan Brito",
        "email": "davigustavoemanuelbrito_@way2goidiomas.com.br",
        "senha": "opBBnWajgg",
        "cep": "44090520",
        "endereco": "Rua Tabapuã",
        "numero": 103,
        "bairro": "Tomba",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7539158521",
        "celular": "75983442194",
        "altura": "1,82",
        "peso": 93,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "laranja"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Analu Isis Freitas",
        "idade": 50,
        "cpf": "73517836591",
        "rg": "239773512",
        "data_nasc": "05\/01\/1969",
        "signo": "Capricórnio",
        "mae": "Rosa Jaqueline",
        "pai": "Raul Giovanni Freitas",
        "email": "analuisisfreitas__analuisisfreitas@bseletronicos.com.br",
        "senha": "9dSsx33euM",
        "cep": "44033349",
        "endereco": "Rua Campo Belo",
        "numero": 414,
        "bairro": "Campo Limpo",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7539745298",
        "celular": "75995780430",
        "altura": "1,53",
        "peso": 70,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB+",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Pedro Henrique Felipe Rodrigo Lima",
        "idade": 26,
        "cpf": "99068101579",
        "rg": "170376758",
        "data_nasc": "02\/09\/1993",
        "signo": "Virgem",
        "mae": "Luiza Ayla",
        "pai": "Rodrigo Ruan Kaique Lima",
        "email": "pedrohenriquefeliperodrigolima..pedrohenriquefeliperodrigolima@numero.com.br",
        "senha": "KIUEDbq2js",
        "cep": "44092684",
        "endereco": "Rua Salmo 29",
        "numero": 535,
        "bairro": "Tomba",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537369181",
        "celular": "75981661177",
        "altura": "1,75",
        "peso": 53,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB-",
        "cor": "preto"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Martin Alexandre Aparício",
        "idade": 56,
        "cpf": "29085293510",
        "rg": "101685099",
        "data_nasc": "17\/05\/1963",
        "signo": "Touro",
        "mae": "Valentina Betina Sandra",
        "pai": "Raul Giovanni Aparício",
        "email": "martinalexandreaparicio_@vlcorporate.com",
        "senha": "jqH0nIrNWr",
        "cep": "44053286",
        "endereco": "Caminho Nazaré",
        "numero": 430,
        "bairro": "Cidade Nova",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7527894365",
        "celular": "75984239491",
        "altura": "1,90",
        "peso": 58,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A+",
        "cor": "preto"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Sarah Simone Duarte",
        "idade": 53,
        "cpf": "01841232599",
        "rg": "450643542",
        "data_nasc": "11\/01\/1966",
        "signo": "Capricórnio",
        "mae": "Bianca Natália Laura",
        "pai": "Benjamin Lorenzo Duarte",
        "email": "sarahsimoneduarte-88@sha.com.br",
        "senha": "e3CiC38JLU",
        "cep": "44053450",
        "endereco": "Caminho Ilhéus",
        "numero": 743,
        "bairro": "Cidade Nova",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537498152",
        "celular": "75996913514",
        "altura": "1,83",
        "peso": 50,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Igor Benedito Rezende",
        "idade": 31,
        "cpf": "33134585561",
        "rg": "473634867",
        "data_nasc": "22\/12\/1988",
        "signo": "Capricórnio",
        "mae": "Agatha Daniela Analu",
        "pai": "Miguel Leandro Rezende",
        "email": "igorbeneditorezende..igorbeneditorezende@arysta.com.br",
        "senha": "MbUiwg3MBw",
        "cep": "44002068",
        "endereco": "Rua Joaquim Pitombo",
        "numero": 965,
        "bairro": "Centro",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537886021",
        "celular": "75986897117",
        "altura": "1,73",
        "peso": 56,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B+",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Emanuelly Maria Cecília Assis",
        "idade": 66,
        "cpf": "69748459527",
        "rg": "208004014",
        "data_nasc": "10\/10\/1953",
        "signo": "Libra",
        "mae": "Débora Stella",
        "pai": "Kauê Igor Rodrigo Assis",
        "email": "emanuellymariaceciliaassis_@fibran.com.br",
        "senha": "zmPciB5Zfg",
        "cep": "44028132",
        "endereco": "Rua Pedra Sobre Pedra",
        "numero": 637,
        "bairro": "Gabriela",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7525123101",
        "celular": "75982401371",
        "altura": "1,79",
        "peso": 69,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "verde"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Simone Agatha Mirella da Silva",
        "idade": 49,
        "cpf": "47097225521",
        "rg": "250982109",
        "data_nasc": "18\/08\/1970",
        "signo": "Leão",
        "mae": "Teresinha Laura",
        "pai": "Julio Carlos Gustavo da Silva",
        "email": "ssimoneagathamirelladasilva@mciimoveis.com.br",
        "senha": "he2CP7ADNR",
        "cep": "44052163",
        "endereco": "Praça da Serra",
        "numero": 681,
        "bairro": "CASEB",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7538641105",
        "celular": "75993339289",
        "altura": "1,73",
        "peso": 59,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Mariah Jaqueline Silva",
        "idade": 76,
        "cpf": "30764782576",
        "rg": "364397354",
        "data_nasc": "11\/01\/1943",
        "signo": "Capricórnio",
        "mae": "Márcia Vera Antonella",
        "pai": "Nicolas Kauê Carlos Silva",
        "email": "mariahjaquelinesilva..mariahjaquelinesilva@galvao.com",
        "senha": "An5WsnBHX4",
        "cep": "44006050",
        "endereco": "Caminho H - XXV",
        "numero": 574,
        "bairro": "Muchila",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7525440777",
        "celular": "75982560255",
        "altura": "1,54",
        "peso": 82,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A+",
        "cor": "verde"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Raimundo Pedro Moreira",
        "idade": 20,
        "cpf": "80247362506",
        "rg": "420456107",
        "data_nasc": "05\/11\/1999",
        "signo": "Escorpião",
        "mae": "Gabrielly Alana",
        "pai": "Cláudio Anderson Moreira",
        "email": "raimundopedromoreira_@patriciagrillo.adv.br",
        "senha": "XT1zBNePFK",
        "cep": "44089138",
        "endereco": "Caminho 36",
        "numero": 493,
        "bairro": "Brasília",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7528891832",
        "celular": "75982344425",
        "altura": "1,91",
        "peso": 60,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Manuel Daniel dos Santos",
        "idade": 26,
        "cpf": "84718261511",
        "rg": "420334282",
        "data_nasc": "20\/08\/1993",
        "signo": "Leão",
        "mae": "Catarina Camila",
        "pai": "Bernardo Samuel dos Santos",
        "email": "manueldanieldossantos..manueldanieldossantos@uol.om.br",
        "senha": "sT0itjslxX",
        "cep": "44003186",
        "endereco": "Rua Presidente Lincoln",
        "numero": 697,
        "bairro": "Serraria Brasil",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537837958",
        "celular": "75997610132",
        "altura": "2,00",
        "peso": 87,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A-",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Cláudia Hadassa Alícia Carvalho",
        "idade": 26,
        "cpf": "10981995535",
        "rg": "186568551",
        "data_nasc": "07\/10\/1993",
        "signo": "Libra",
        "mae": "Silvana Emanuelly Betina",
        "pai": "Geraldo Cláudio Mateus Carvalho",
        "email": "claudiahadassaaliciacarvalho_@afsn.com.br",
        "senha": "9gxKgq8rm3",
        "cep": "44094516",
        "endereco": "Rua Torneira",
        "numero": 139,
        "bairro": "35º BI",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7527692439",
        "celular": "75997020636",
        "altura": "1,54",
        "peso": 59,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A+",
        "cor": "laranja"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Lorena Aparecida Agatha Cardoso",
        "idade": 48,
        "cpf": "88791755565",
        "rg": "265730399",
        "data_nasc": "02\/07\/1971",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Jaqueline Emilly Antonella",
        "pai": "Luiz Thiago Osvaldo Cardoso",
        "email": "lorenaaparecidaagathacardoso_@pop.com.br",
        "senha": "LhoBaZ6hKg",
        "cep": "44013270",
        "endereco": "Via Pedestre 7",
        "numero": 270,
        "bairro": "CIS",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537872565",
        "celular": "75982619266",
        "altura": "1,81",
        "peso": 86,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A+",
        "cor": "vermelho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Luzia Jaqueline Isabela Cardoso",
        "idade": 58,
        "cpf": "44206232504",
        "rg": "445488207",
        "data_nasc": "17\/01\/1961",
        "signo": "Capricórnio",
        "mae": "Nina Josefa Maria",
        "pai": "Benedito Benício Severino Cardoso",
        "email": "luziajaquelineisabelacardoso_@mfb.com.br",
        "senha": "iNnAq6DTJZ",
        "cep": "44078150",
        "endereco": "Rua São Miguel do Sul",
        "numero": 555,
        "bairro": "Santa Mônica",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7536957008",
        "celular": "75992949604",
        "altura": "1,55",
        "peso": 88,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B-",
        "cor": "vermelho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Melissa Adriana Assunção",
        "idade": 45,
        "cpf": "32126187527",
        "rg": "364499394",
        "data_nasc": "13\/07\/1974",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Helena Ayla Brenda",
        "pai": "Kaique Ruan Assunção",
        "email": "melissaadrianaassuncao_@arosacampinas.com.br",
        "senha": "F4hYHtou3h",
        "cep": "44066288",
        "endereco": "Travessa Boa Esperança",
        "numero": 367,
        "bairro": "Conceição",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7528259495",
        "celular": "75988994634",
        "altura": "1,69",
        "peso": 65,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B-",
        "cor": "vermelho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Martin Matheus Rodrigo da Paz",
        "idade": 22,
        "cpf": "59758112520",
        "rg": "362671266",
        "data_nasc": "19\/10\/1997",
        "signo": "Libra",
        "mae": "Milena Maria Lara",
        "pai": "Anthony João da Paz",
        "email": "mmartinmatheusrodrigodapaz@jonasmartinez.com",
        "senha": "5sLdm79cIJ",
        "cep": "44050084",
        "endereco": "Rua Carlos Valadares",
        "numero": 265,
        "bairro": "Queimadinha",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7536930884",
        "celular": "75988813922",
        "altura": "1,79",
        "peso": 110,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "O+",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Nathan Márcio Galvão",
        "idade": 74,
        "cpf": "50142434523",
        "rg": "497678172",
        "data_nasc": "09\/07\/1945",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Clarice Flávia",
        "pai": "Joaquim Antonio Galvão",
        "email": "nathanmarciogalvao__nathanmarciogalvao@catsfeelings.com.br",
        "senha": "ZdT1pxNIjg",
        "cep": "44056518",
        "endereco": "Rua Japurá",
        "numero": 924,
        "bairro": "Mangabeira",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7536099837",
        "celular": "75995878841",
        "altura": "1,88",
        "peso": 53,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "A-",
        "cor": "verde"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Filipe Igor Breno Almeida",
        "idade": 49,
        "cpf": "11799683524",
        "rg": "432668299",
        "data_nasc": "23\/10\/1970",
        "signo": "Escorpião",
        "mae": "Clarice Lorena Patrícia",
        "pai": "Bryan Sebastião Almeida",
        "email": "filipeigorbrenoalmeida__filipeigorbrenoalmeida@ggm.com.br",
        "senha": "6UhGhUEd95",
        "cep": "44023054",
        "endereco": "Rua Ubatã",
        "numero": 225,
        "bairro": "Rua Nova",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7527936589",
        "celular": "75982142592",
        "altura": "1,74",
        "peso": 73,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB-",
        "cor": "azul"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Otávio José Thiago Nunes",
        "idade": 74,
        "cpf": "84799949594",
        "rg": "154312617",
        "data_nasc": "10\/12\/1945",
        "signo": "Sagitário",
        "mae": "Fernanda Heloise Marcela",
        "pai": "Anthony Paulo André Nunes",
        "email": "otaviojosethiagonunes..otaviojosethiagonunes@vinax.com.br",
        "senha": "uEOjg6fc19",
        "cep": "44044377",
        "endereco": "Travessa Valter Carneiro",
        "numero": 711,
        "bairro": "Asa Branca",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7539062051",
        "celular": "75997770966",
        "altura": "1,76",
        "peso": 100,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB-",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Noah Victor Fernando Oliveira",
        "idade": 61,
        "cpf": "85853859528",
        "rg": "332980649",
        "data_nasc": "13\/08\/1958",
        "signo": "Leão",
        "mae": "Tereza Francisca",
        "pai": "José Carlos Eduardo Oliveira",
        "email": "noahvictorfernandooliveira_@mailinator.com",
        "senha": "LpXALMkeDH",
        "cep": "44080636",
        "endereco": "Rua Tabuleiro do Norte",
        "numero": 819,
        "bairro": "Subaé",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7537730634",
        "celular": "75997027492",
        "altura": "1,88",
        "peso": 93,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "AB+",
        "cor": "roxo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Lucas Yuri Isaac Silva",
        "idade": 28,
        "cpf": "53766516574",
        "rg": "422942777",
        "data_nasc": "02\/07\/1991",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Raimunda Andreia Isis",
        "pai": "Luís Fernando Silva",
        "email": "lucasyuriisaacsilva_@hotmai.com.br",
        "senha": "Raa2xMfasl",
        "cep": "44097776",
        "endereco": "Rua Brejo de Madre de Deus",
        "numero": 252,
        "bairro": "Limoeiro",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7527389404",
        "celular": "75985947164",
        "altura": "1,91",
        "peso": 60,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B+",
        "cor": "vermelho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Clarice Pietra Farias",
        "idade": 21,
        "cpf": "15510327596",
        "rg": "395591405",
        "data_nasc": "05\/07\/1998",
        "signo": "Câncer",
        "mae": "Nair Josefa Ester",
        "pai": "Marcos Benjamin Carlos Farias",
        "email": "claricepietrafarias_@lagencemodelos.com.br",
        "senha": "P14bZdlcx2",
        "cep": "44086390",
        "endereco": "Rua Itapetim",
        "numero": 235,
        "bairro": "SIM",
        "cidade": "Feira de Santana",
        "estado": "BA",
        "telefone_fixo": "7529393054",
        "celular": "75995736537",
        "altura": "1,67",
        "peso": 79,
        "tipo_sanguineo": "B+",
        "cor": "roxo"
    }
]
```

Esse .Json tem o cadastro de 30 Clientes tenho que pegar um a um e por no banco de dados só não sei como proceder nos tópos visto aqui no pt.stackoverflow vi como abrir o *.json* mais pegar os cada um dos clientes não consegui.

Seque o código que já tenho

```
procedure TfrmClienteJSON.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JSArray  : TJSONArray;
  JSValue  : TJSONValue;
begin
  jsonObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JSonObjectAsString), 0) as TJSONObject;
end;

procedure TfrmClienteJSON.btnAbrirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   StringList : TStringList;
begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;

  if OpenDialog.Execute then
  begin
    try
      StringList.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
      // Joga arquivo carregado na StringList na sua variável;
      JSonObjectAsString := StringList.Text;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(StringList);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Olá. Qual é a versão do delphi que você usa?

Comment: Em tempo, esses dados que você postou no json são dados reais? Se for, por favor, retire-os e substitua por dados descaracterizados. Não deixe dados reais que sejam pessoais ou sensíveis expostos na internet. Lembre-se da LGPD.

Comment: Uso Delphi 10.2
Não são dados gerados em um Fake Name Generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta armazenar o conteúdo json utilizando um memo e um Listbox pra listar o conteúdo

```pascal
var
  jsonObj, jSubObj: TJSONObject;
  JSArray  : TJSONArray;
  JSValue  : TJSONValue;
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
begin
  jsonObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Text), 0) as TJSONObject;
  for j := 0 to jsonObject.Size - 1 do
  begin
    JSValue := jsonObj.Get(j).JsonValue;
    JSArray := JSValue as TJSONArray;
  end;

  ListBox1.Clear;

  for i := 0 to JSArray.Size - 1 do
  begin
    jSubObj := (JSArray.Get(i) as TJSONObject);
    JSValue := jSubObj.Get(0).JsonValue;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(JSValue.Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Tales, está apresentando essa Msg:

[dcc32 Error] U.pas(166): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Get' that can be called with these arguments
[dcc32 Warning] U.pas(166): W1000 Symbol 'Get' is deprecated:

Comment: tinha faltado passar um parâmetro no get, testa agora, ajustei o código

Comment: Modei a linha `jsonObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Text), 0) as TJSONObject;` por que `ASCII` não estava mostrando os nomes com os acentos, fora isso tudo deu certo. agora eu já sei como fazer a leitura desse tipo de arquivo. Valeu.